# Graphic driver versions available for Ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia, version, cuda

I have Nvidia GTX 1080Ti and according to Nvidia's website the latest driver version is 460. I tried to install this and failed. With the **.run** file nothing got installed. With ppa and `ubuntu-drivers devices` the latest version displayed is 430. This [link](https://launchpad.net/%7Egraphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) implies that 430 is the best driver version for Ubuntu 16. But that can't be. Can it?
I didn't find any forums explicitly saying this. If I need to use the latest CUDA version I need higher graphic driver versions. My current conclusion is that I need to install Ubuntu 18 or Ubuntu 20. I'm not experienced in this area. Please tell me if all driver versions provided in Nvidia website can be installed in Ubuntu 16.

Answer (score 0):

You should use distro provided NVIDIA Linux drivers whenever possible because they are packaged properly and are tested to work with your distro.

The drivers provided directly by NVIDIA are meant only for experienced users or IT professionals.

I've dug around and unfortunately I've been unable to find 460.* drivers for your Ubuntu version. The best I've found is: [https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Egraphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) but this PPA seemingly supports only Ubuntu 18 an 20.

The new drivers will be eventually released for your Ubuntu version, so I guess you'll just have to wait.